# How to use invisible character to split a text and how to get it's JS representation?

Tags: javascript, string, spacing

On LinkedIn, I want to add invisible characters so I can split the text and use data to generate my resume.

I am looking for a list of invisible characters with their JavaScript representation.

What unused invisible character should I use to split my text?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a website: [emptycharacter.com](https://emptycharacter.com/)

```
Unicode HTML    Description Example
U+0020  &#32    Space   [ ]
U+00A0  &#160   No-Break Space  [ ]
U+2000  &#8192  En Quad [ ]
U+2001  &#8193  Em Quad [ ]
U+2002  &#8194  En Space    [ ]
U+2003  &#8195  Em Space    [ ]
U+2004  &#8196  Three-Per-Em Space  [ ]
U+2005  &#8197  Four-Per-Em Space   [ ]
U+2006  &#8198  Six-Per-Em Space    [ ]
U+2007  &#8199  Figure Space    [ ]
U+2008  &#8200  Punctuation Space   [ ]
U+2009  &#8201  Thin Space  [ ]
U+200A  &#8202  Hair Space  [ ]
U+2028  &#8232  Line Separator  [ ]
U+205F  &#8287  Medium Mathematical Space   [ ]
U+3000  &#12288 Ideographic Space   [　]
```

This is the same characters in unicode:

```js
console.log('\u0020');
console.log('\u00a0');
console.log('\u2000');
console.log('\u2001');
console.log('\u2002');
console.log('\u2003');
console.log('\u2004');
console.log('\u2005');
console.log('\u2006');
console.log('\u2007');
console.log('\u2008');
console.log('\u2009');
console.log('\u200a');
console.log('\u2028');
console.log('\u205f');
console.log('\u3000');
```